# find files by extension containing certain text and display the file path and modified date

Tags: bash, grep, find, stat

I need to find all .txt files containing "abc" in their content and display the filepath and modified date:

Maybe something like:

```
> find /folder -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i -n -l "abc" | xargs echo <filepath> <modified_date>
```

Expected output:

```
/folder/hello.txt 2017-12-12 32:56:23
/folder/d1/d2/hey.txt 2017-12-12 32:56:23
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have GNU `find`, so you can use the `-printf` predicate. This should get you on the right track:

```
find /folder -iname '*.txt' -type f -exec grep -q 'abc' {} \; -printf '%p %Tx %Tr\n'
```

The `%T` modifier for the `-printf` predicate is what you're looking for. The funny `x` and `r` are for the date and time. More information from `man find`:

```
                 @      seconds  since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with frac‐
                        tional part.

                 Time fields:

                 H      hour (00..23)

                 I      hour (01..12)

                 k      hour ( 0..23)

                 l      hour ( 1..12)

                 M      minute (00..59)

                 p      locale's AM or PM

                 r      time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss [AP]M)

                 S      Second (00.00 .. 61.00).  There  is  a  fractional
                        part.

                 T      time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss.xxxxxxxxxx)

                 +      Date  and  time,  separated  by  `+',  for example
                        `2004-04-28+22:22:05.0'.  This is a GNU extension.
                        The  time  is given in the current timezone (which
                        may be affected  by  setting  the  TZ  environment
                        variable).   The  seconds  field  includes a frac‐
                        tional part.

                 X      locale's time representation (H:M:S).  The seconds
                        field includes a fractional part.

                 Z      time  zone (e.g., EDT), or nothing if no time zone
                        is determinable

                 Date fields:

                 a      locale's abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)

                 A      locale's full weekday name, variable length  (Sun‐
                        day..Saturday)

                 b      locale's abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)

                 B      locale's  full  month name, variable length (Janu‐
                        ary..December)

                 c      locale's date and time (Sat Nov  04  12:02:33  EST
                        1989).  The format is the same as for ctime(3) and
                        so to preserve  compatibility  with  that  format,
                        there is no fractional part in the seconds field.

                 d      day of month (01..31)

                 D      date (mm/dd/yy)

                 h      same as b

                 j      day of year (001..366)

                 m      month (01..12)

                 U      week  number  of  year with Sunday as first day of
                        week (00..53)

                 w      day of week (0..6)

                 W      week number of year with Monday as  first  day  of
                        week (00..53)

                 x      locale's date representation (mm/dd/yy)

                 y      last two digits of year (00..99)

                 Y      year (1970...)
```